# component.find("Name").get("v.value"); is not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components

i am encountering error with below

```
Var req_val= cmp.find("required").get("v.value");
```

earlier it was working fine, now it is not working getting

error

```
Uncaught Action failed: c$my_comp$controller$closeTask [TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined]
```

i am calling this function from Event

```
closeTask:function(cmp,event,helper){
console.log(cmp.find('required').get('v.value'));// here is the error
```

var eventId = event.getParam("recordId");

Event is registered in child and handling in parent. it consist of recordId.

required attribute is in parent. cant we get this attribute value in parent am getting as undefined.

please suggest.

Comment: Please add some more code

Comment: Please if you could share sample code snippets it's easier to assist you

Comment: Hi Mohit, i added little bit code and explained how am using it.

Comment: Find is used on DOM aura Id .

Comment: Cant we get the aura:id or aura:attribute value of parent in this scenario. i am still getting undefined event with attribute cmp.get("parentAttribute"); or cmp.find("prntDom").get("v.value");

Comment: add you parent and child component code to make it clear

Answer (score 2):

create an aura:Attribute in your event, which you should pass while invoking the event

Aura attribute in event -

```
<aura:attribute name="sObjectId" type="Id" required="true" description="The Id of the selected SObject." />
```

While invoking event -
    var updateEvent = cmp.getEvent("eventName");

```
// Populate the event with the selected Object Id
updateEvent.setParams({
    "sObjectId" : value
});
```

In the event handler's action write following -

```
// Get the Id from the Event
var accountId = event.getParam("sObjectId");
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The issue is user getting undefined which he is not expecting and expecting a value .Its not about how to avoid error here

Comment: Thank you sneha, i was good with that , but had problem with parent tag DOM ID , am getting undefined if i use that DOM ID in `cmp.find('auraId');`

Answer (score 1):

Find function is always used with aura local Id .Please check how to [use it](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_find_by_id.htm)

While get function is used to get the attribute value

Try this

```
cmp.get(""required"");
```

Comment: Hi Mohit, as of now  am not able to find the value with DOM id (this tag value is attribute value that am changing dynamically) still undefined but i am getting the value based on attribute `cmp.get("v.required_attr");` .   Thank you for suggestion. Apologies not pasting code here as am not working own dev org.